# Multiple requestmapping value with path variables from thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, request-mapping, path-variables

I have to send two data from `thymeleaf` to `controller` like this in `a th:href`:

```
<table id="itemTable" class="deneme">
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="item : ${list.items}">
        <td>
            <p th:text="${item.content}"/>
            <a th:href="@{/deleteItem/{listId}(listId=${list.id})/{itemId}(itemId=${item.id})}">
                <span>Delet‌​e</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("/deleteItem/{listId}/{itemId}")
public String deleteItem(Model model, @PathVariable(value = "listId") Integer listId, @PathVariable(value = "itemId") int itemId) {
    ...
    return "list";
}
```

`itemId` is coming with the true value but `listId` is coming as `{listId}(listId=${toDoList.id})`

What is the problem exactly? Please help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for multiple parameters looks like this:

```
<a th:href="@{/deleteItem/{listId}/{itemId}(listId=${list.id},itemId=${item.id})}"><span>Delet‌​e</span></a>
```

Comment: Yeah! Exactly true. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must define the @PathVariables in your Thymeleaf as comma-separated definitions within a single (paranthesis)
So the syntax would be in the following form:

```
<a th:href="@{/deleteItem/{listId}/{itemId}(listId=${list.id},itemId=${item.id})}"><span>Delet‌​e</span></a>
```

Notice how the definitions are within the same paranthesis, only after PathVariable have been declared.